# MonetDB: How to count in last N rows?

Tags: sql, monetdb

This one is not working

`select count(*) from table where col = 'value' order by id desc limit 100`

Error: `identifier 'id' unknown`

This also not working

`select count(*) from (select * from table order by id desc limit 100) as temp where col = 'value'`

Error: `syntax error, unexpected ORDER, expecting UNION or EXCEPT or INTERSECT or ')'`

Same if I will use `offset ...` instead of `order by ... desc limit ...` - `syntax error, unexpected OFFSET`

The only one way I found is to get count of all rows in table and

`select count(*) from (select ROW_NUMBER() over () as n, table.* from table) as temp where n > %COUNT% - 100 and col = 'value'`

Is there better way to do count in N last rows?

Comment: maybe not?  your first query definitely won't work and your second query has a `limit` in the subquery, which is illegal

Comment: @AnthonyDamico second query is legal in postgresql, as we see in monet it not

Comment: monetdb strictly follows the sql standard, which says `limit` can only occur on the outermost query

Comment: As far as I know, your last query is the only option. As a general remark, be careful with what you mean by "last". If you really want the "last N as they are stored", no matter which ones, this is ok. If by that you expect to match an assumed order on some column, then enforce that order in the `over ()` subclause. Also, you seemed to expect that `id` implicitly gives you the result of the `row_number()` clause. In MonetDB, `id` has no implicit meaning.